# Python 2.7: Error for no reason - 'Invalid Syntax' on for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, graphics, syntax-error

I'm trying to do a chess board, but when it comes to the black sqares, im gettnig the following error:

```
      File "C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\Aplicativos\NONIOInforestudante\Licenciatura em BioquÝmica\2015 2016\2.║ Semestre\Computadores e ProgramaþÒo\graph\f10-p1.py", line 17
    yi = margem+((a-1)*(largura/8))
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is the code:

```
#from graphics import *
import graphics

largura = 500
comprimento = 500
margem = 20

janela = graphics.GraphWin('Janela', comprimento+2*margem, largura+2*margem)
janela.setBackground('grey')
c = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(margem, margem), graphics.Point(comprimento+margem,largura+margem))
c.setFill('white')
c.setOutline('black')
c.setWidth(1)
c.draw(janela)
for a in range(1,8,2):
    xi = margem+(a*(comprimento/8)
    yi = margem+((a-1)*(largura/8))
    xf = margem+(a*((comprimento/8)*2)
    yf = margem+(a*largura/8)
    c = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(xi, yi),graphics.Point(xf, yf)
    c.setFill('black')
    c.draw(janela)
janela.getMouse()
janela.close
```

Can you please explain me what's the problem?

Comment: By the way, `janela.close` does not do anything.  You should say `janela.close()` instead.

Comment: you are missing `)` at three lines starting with `xi`, `xf` and `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line xi = `margem+(a*(comprimento/8)` you are missing a closing bracket.

try

```
xi = margem+(a*(comprimento/8))
```

Comment: Questions that are just typographical errors should be answered *in the comments* and closed.  Please don't clutter Stack Overflow with answers that are not helpful to future readers.  Instead, we would like to close these questions so that they will eventually be deleted.